# In OSI layers, where does JMeter Proxy records

Tags: jmeter

We use a proxy server to record the request and response of an application. In OSI layer, where does this jmeter records?

My assumption is that "It records between Session layer and transport layer"

Answer (score 1):

Pretty Sure HTTP/HTTPS in context of recording TCP traffic with Jmeter and the like,  takes place at the transport layer and TCP.    TLS,  obviously will kind of give that away from the jump.  But it's more important, perhaps, to understand the context.

Answer (score 0):

As per [JMeter 5.1](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-5.1/) only following protocols are supported for recording:

- [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP)
- [HTTPS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/https)

as it evidenced by [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) test element name.

Looking into [OSI Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) both HTTP and HTTPS protocols belong to [Application Layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model#Layer_7:_Application_Layer) therefore JMeter is recording on top level 7 of the OSI model pyramid.